# How to make the best use of indexes in mysql?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I have to select values from a table which has about 1 million entries.
Which of my query will be more efficient?

Query 1:

```
select * from table1 
where indexedcolumn1 < value1 
and unindexedcolumn1 < value 2 
and indexedcolumn2 < value2;
```

Query 2:

```
select * from table1 
where indexedcolumn1 < value1 
and indexedcolumn2 < value2 
and unindexedcolumn1 < value 2;
```

How to make the best use of indexes?

Comment: We can't answer this, because we don't know your data, and we can't see the explain plan.  You should add these things to your question.

Comment: looking to your code the two query are the same the change of a position inside the where clause should don't change performance  ..but you shoudl show a real case ..

Comment: Because you have one (or more) unindexed columns appearing in the `WHERE` clause, most likely MySQL would choose to not use any index at all.  You could rephrase your question by describing an actual query you want to run, and then ask for help in optimizing it.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/ should be required reading.

Answer (score 0):

1. Whe sequence of conditions (columns) in WHERE clause doesn't make any sence as the mySQL query optimizer doesn't take it into consideration. So (as mentioned above) your queries are identical.
2. Use EXPLAIN (example: explain select * from ....) command to find out the way your queries were executed by the server. Read more on interpreting EXPLAIN output in the official docs on on google (there's a number of good articles on EXPLAIN out there).
3. Try to index the unindexed column as this is the best (and I guess - the only one) way to increase performance of your queries. One unindexed column usually ruins all the other efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Index each of the 3 columns.  The Optimizer will pick the best index based on statistics.  It may still use the wrong index, but it is the best current available.